# Get every char that's bigger than 'G'

Tags: c#, .net

Well I have an array which called names

```
string[] names = new string[] { "Brad", "Ava", "Tom", "Cooper"};
```

Now I want to get every char of a name which is greater than `'g'`. With greater I mean every char after `'g'` so `h,i,j,k,l ...`

This is what I already got

```
names.Select(x => x.ToCharArray()).ToString().ToUpper().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Expected result:

```
R
V
MOT
OOPR
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make names uppercase and filter by checking if characters are bigger than character `'G'`:

```
string[] result = names.Select(s => string.Concat(s.ToUpper()
                                                   .OrderBy(ch => ch)
                                                   .Where(ch => ch > 'G')))
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd like to order the letter from a name with order by. Expected result when Tom is MOT

Comment: Edit your question/expected result, please. If I understood you correctly, you can do that either after `ToUpper` or `string.Concat` (just add `.OrderBy(c => c)`)

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] names = new string[] { "Brad", "Ava", "Tom", "Cooper" };
        char g = 'G';
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            foreach (var c in name.ToUpper())
                if ((int)c > (int)g)
                    Console.Write(c);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: There is no need to cast `char` to `int`.